# MYSQL Insert .. Select - Multiple rows & tables with foreign keys?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm using an INSERT .. SELECT to 'duplicate' rows from a table (with a different foreign key).

This works fine, however it's inserting multiple rows and I now need to do another INSERT to insert multiple rows that are linked to each individual row in the previous SELECT... does that even make sense? Haha.

Basically there's a one to many relationship between table1 and table2. There's a one to one relationship between table1 and table3. I'm 'assigning' rows from table1(and their relevant linked table2 rows) to a new row on table3 (i have the mysql_insert_id for this one). I'm trying to do it with as few queries as possible.

I'll give an example,

---

You have a `products` table an `options` table and an `option_items` table. Each `option` has multiple `option_items` and each `product` can have multiple `options` applied to it.

`Product1` has the option `Colour` applied to it, and `Colour` has the items `Blue` and `Green`, `Product1` also has the `Size` option applied to it which has the items `Small` and `Large`.

I wish to duplicate the product with a new ID, which means duplicating the rows in both the `options` and `option_items` tables and re-creating their relating foreign keys.

I've created the new product and have the productid.

Now I need to duplicate the options get the id of the new `option`, duplicate the items and assign the ID of the newly created `option` to the `items` (maintaining the option to item relationships).

Any help would be muchly appreciated!

Comment: nope, doesn't make sense. please edit and provide some sample data.

Comment: I've added an example to hopefully help.

Comment: please add table DDL and sample queries (the ones you've been able to figure out so far) so we can visualize what you're trying to do. Otherwise it's too hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the crap question! I ended up just using a loop instead of complicated queries. Probably not the best solution, but by far the most straight forward :)

Thanks for reading guys.